# How to copy a dynamic range or data to another sheet using google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a named ranged called MW_DATA in my sheet which covers the range U12:AA105

Based on the data present there could be a variable number of rows of data in U12:AA105 every time I copy the data to a Games_Log sheet and clear the data in the cells.

I need to improve the code so the filteredData variable is a dynamic range of rows each time (e.g. it could be U12:AA12 or U12:AA75)

**current code:**

```
function SaveMWData() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Games_Log");
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataLocation = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var mwData = sheet.getRange("MW_DATA");

  mwData.copyTo(dataSheet.getRange(dataLocation + 1,1),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Above code keeps copying all rows, including blank rows into the Games_Log sheet

**Code I can't figure out:**

```
function SaveMWData() {
  var unfilteredData = sheet.getRange("MW_DATA");
  var filteredData = ?? 

  filteredData.copyTo(dataSheet.getRange(dataLocation + 1,1),{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Filtered data would only copy over the rows with data

Answer (score 0):

I believe I got it working as follow:

```
function SaveMWData() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Games_Log");
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataLocation = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var row = sheet.getRange("MW_ROW").getValue();
  var column = sheet.getRange("MW_COLUMN").getValue();
  var numrows = sheet.getRange("MW_NUMROWS").getValue();
  var numcolumns = sheet.getRange("MW_NUMCOLUMNS").getValue();
  var mwData = sheet.getRange(row,column,numrows,numcolumns);

  mwData.copyTo(dataSheet.getRange(dataLocation + 1,1),{contentsOnly:true});

}
```